# Air conditioners, heat or cold

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, everyday-life

How comes in the summer I put the AC on cooler at 23C and the room is cold, and in the winter I put the heat on 23C and the room is hot.
In the end of the day, the machine is trying to heat the room to the same temperature. Whats the difference?

Answer (score 2):

What clothes do you wear in summer? Where did you come from when you walked into that "cold" room with the AC at 23?

Same question in winter...

This is about perception of hot or cold. If you are warmly dressed, coming in from the cold 23 C will feel very warm. If you are sweaty and it was hot outside, the same temperature will feel cooler. Part of this has to do with evaporation - moist skin loses heat due to evaporation.

Comment: Not sure about this. I can stay inside, and stand in front of the AC machine. In the summer, its blowing out cold air. In the winter, its blowing out hot air. But the temperature is the same?

Comment: In order to keep the room at 23 C, the air from the air conditioner has to be below 23 C (because heat is coming in from outside). When it's cold outside, you have to add air "hotter than 23 C" to maintain the average temperature in the room.

Answer (score 0):

Your body also has a heating system that will try to maintain its core temperature to about 36.8 C while also regulating the metabolic rate by burning more or less energy and increasing or decreasing heat loss via sweating and opening or closing blood vessels in the exterior parts of the body. In winter your body adapts to lower temperatures, so you'll feel warm at lower temperatures compared to summer. With the right training, you can swim in ice cold water while that will feel like swimming in tropical water to you, [see here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUQwFZ_xFdM)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have a heat pump system or something similar.

When set to cooling it knows it should be supplying cold air until it measures 23 degrees.   When set to heating it knows it should be supplying warm air until it reaches 23 degrees.

It is because it can be reversed into heating and cooling loops.